# Export GitHub Repository Files to a Usable JAR executable file, issues

Tags: java, eclipse, github, jar

I am an enthusiast attempting to play around and add things to an app that I have been using for the past year which the source codes are available in GitHub. Problem is when I clone or download the repository and open it in Eclipse, I get a ton of error codes whenever I try to 'run as' Java app (in particular I am unable to find the 'main class/starting point' there's way too many files to chose from to find it and most don't work) and when I try to extract the files to an executable jar it gives me a JAR exe that is unusable :-(. I know that the files are workable since I do use the executable jar that is available from the developer and others have also toyed around with the source codes.

Can anyone assist me with this? Maybe I am using the wrong Java manipulator/application. The program I am using for opening these files is Eclipse IDE for Java Developers and my operating system is 64bit Windows 10.

Also, here is the GitHub URL for the repository, in case anyone asks: https://github.com/DraqueT/PolyGlot.

I thank anyone who can be of some assistance as I have been working on this forever and can't seem to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The github project looks a lot like a utility library than a full application. But the following could help:

1. Try to study the README file attached to the github project. (There is one in the source code according to the author). This would help you to setup the project.
2. Make sure to download all the dependencies for that project. Again, the author has provided some of them in the github project (I could see some Apache POI libraries in there somewhere), but getting the required jars on the maven repository isn't that difficult.
3. It would also help to know what type of project it is. For example, having a `main` method in a web application doesn't do much for you, but a Java SE project would need a main method to run. So try to find out what kind of project it is.
4. If all else fails, you could try to contact the owner of the repository or one of its contributors to assist you.
   Cheers!